# Macro with countif excluding other values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which helps me to do the countif function between 2 data sets and see if all data specified as "Ours" was included in the data set specified as "theirs". This macro works fine for other data comparisons. However, I would like to compare countries where at the bottom I might have the value Rest of Europe (if this is European list) or Rest of US (when there is an American list with states provided). Is there a way to amend it this way that if it meets the value "Rest of Europe" it will check for everything else than the values which appeared above it - so in other words: Everything what appeared in the range B2:B7 should be excluded from it. The range is not the same for every data set, so it should adjust to the length (same like it happens right now). Rest of Europe / Rest of US would always be at the end of the list. Could anyone help me with this?

Screenshot

[image]

**MY MACRO:**

```
Sub GOOD_ALMOST_C_Countif_Until_LastRow()

Dim LastRowColumnB As Long
LastRowColumnB = Range("B65000").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRowColumnB
Cells(i, 3) = Application.CountIf(Range("A:A"), Cells(i, 2))
Next
End Sub
```

p.s. - I did the internet research before posting this question. However, my research didn't bring any positive results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest idea exactly for your non-dynamic data range (just some mathematics):

```
If Cells(i,2) = "Rest of Europe" Then
    Cells(i,3) = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1 - _
                 WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(2,3), Cells(i-1, 3)))
End If
```

Assuming, that you have only European countries in A:A

Comment: both codes (your's and Daniel's) work fine. Yours seems to be much simpler and for my purposes easier to use. What I would like to do with this code is making it non-case sensitive (in case somebody decides to put "rest of Europe" instead of "Rest of Europe" and ruin the code). I know that normally while using the functions I should use =SUBSTITUTE(). However, how should I amend your code to make substitute function work?

Comment: change the first line into: `If UCase(Cells(i,2)) = "REST OF EUROPE" Then`